# ModRewrite Syntax

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I was wondering if anyone could explain the syntax, or has found a good tutorial on the syntax used by the mod_rewrite module?

I have looked at various examples and *think* I know what's going on, but now that i'm wanting to write my own rules I need to be 100%

I feel the apache documentation while shows you where to the put the code quite well, does nothing for explaining the logic.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Olivier I have moved my comments into an answer … seems appropriate now that I understood the scope of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax used by ModRewrite to describe URLs and their rewrites use [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). Familiarise yourself with this concept and the rest should follow quite easily.

In general, a rewrite rule has the form

```
RewriteRule from to [options]
```

Where `from` is a regular expression matching the source URI and `to` is the target with optional replacements (these are also described in the reference given above).

Comment: I think this grossly oversimplifies the problem. For example what is the URI? `www.example.com/foo/bar.php`? `/foo/bar.php`? `foo/bar.php`? When do we use `$1` versus `%1`. What is ReWriteBase? And not to mention the headache from skipping rules (`S=k`)

Comment: @puk This answer was preceded by a (now deleted) discussion in the comments. It turned out that what the OP *really* wanted was a resource on regular expressions.

Comment: @puk Don’t, it’s not your fault, the comments shouldn’t have been deleted.